# Echarts - about the breakpoints in line chart

Tags: echarts

firtstly, forgive for my poor english :(
here is my options.

```
var option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [1, 2, null, 4, null, 6, 7],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
}
```

to resolve a case that all data like [null, 4, null] should show symbol in data '4', but not show symbol in [null, 6, 7].
I tried to set symbolSize for every single in data like

```
series: [
    {
        data: [1, 2, null, 4, null, 6, 7],
        type: 'line',
        symbolSize: (value, params) => {
            const index = params.dataIndex
            const pre = data[index - 1]
            const next = data[index + 1]
            return (pre === null && value !== null && next === null) ? 4 : 0
        }
    }
]
```

it works well in breakpoints.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPUfC.png)
but when hovering into the non-null data, the symbol is almost disappeared, because the symbol size is 0.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIK60.png)
is there any way to make the non-null data symbol shown at normal size (e.g. 4) only on hover, and the data between null also show symbol?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly how you want to set the symbol sizes. Please see if this [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/px9ov1ec/1/) is what you want,  and if not, please specify the `symbolSize` for each of the seven data points in your example, both in normal and emphasis modes, so one can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @kikon that's exactly what i want, it seems the key is to make ```symbolSize = 0.01``` instead of ```symbolSize = 0``` for non-breakpoint data. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, in essence, - and in this it might be useful to others - how to
make a line plot with point symbols that are not normally visible, but appear
at their usual size in emphasized mode (that is when hovered, or target of the
active tooltip).

To resume the explanations that follow, one can do that by setting the size of the
symbol in the normal state (through `symbolSize`) to a value that is small
enough not to produce any visible symbols *but still greater than zero*, e.g.
`symbolSize: 0.01`; that under the condition that `emphasis.scale` property is not set.

Currently, echarts doesn't allow to explicitly set the size of the symbols in
emphasize mode. It allows one to set the size of the symbols in normal mode,
through [`series[].symbolSize`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.symbolSize) - that can be a number, an array (for each
data point) or a function. The size of the symbol in emphasized mode can be
controlled via [`series[].emphasis.scale`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.emphasis.scale).

If the value of `emphasis.scale` is set, then the size of emphasized symbol is
`emphasis.scale` x the normal size; if it is not set, the size of the symbol in emphasized state
is computed thus:

- if the symbol in normal state has size zero, the emphasised symbol will have the standard size,
  which is 2x2
- if the symbol in normal state has a size greater than zero, the emphasized symbol will
  have a size that is the maximum of the normal size x 1.1 and the *standard size*(the size of the raw symbol)
  = 2 x 3, see the source file [chart/helper/Symbol.ts at line 341 et. seq](https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/master/src/chart/helper/Symbol.ts#L341)

This means that if we set the normal symbol size to 0.01, its size in normal mode will be too
small for it to be visible, but in emphasized mode its size will be 6x6.

The solution to the OP question involves a line plot with gaps in the data, with
some isolated points that *should* have a visible normal state size of 4, while all the others
should not appear (size = 0 --> 0.01). Since 4*1.1 is still under 6, it follows that all data points
will have an emphasis size of 6.

```js
const dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
const data = [1, 2, null, 4, null, 6, 7];
const option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
        
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            dataView:{
                _optionToContent: function(opt){
                    console.log(opt);
                },
                show: true
            },
            
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            data,
            symbolSize: (value, params) => {
                const index = params.dataIndex
                const pre = data[index - 1]
                const next = data[index + 1]
                return (pre === null && value !== null && next === null) ? 4 : 0.01
            },
            // emphasis:{
            //    scale: 1, // don't set this
            // },
            type: 'line'
        }
    ]
}

const myChart = echarts.init(dom);
myChart.setOption(option);
window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#chart-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.1/echarts.min.js"></script>
```